# How to create SVG file from Bitmap in Android Programmatically?

Tags: java, android, svg, vector, bitmap

I need to convert jpeg & bitmap image to vector file (.SVG). Is there a library to do this? Or a source that I can not use it?

Comment: check out http://potrace.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/)

from their description

> Potrace(TM) is a tool for tracing a bitmap, which means, transforming a bitmap into a smooth, scalable image. The input is a bitmap (PBM, PGM, PPM, or BMP format), and the default output is an encapsulated PostScript file (EPS). A typical use is to create EPS files from scanned data, such as company or university logos, handwritten notes, etc. The resulting image is not "jaggy" like a bitmap, but smooth. It can then be rendered at any resolution.
>
> Potrace can currently produce the following output formats: EPS, PostScript, PDF, SVG (scalable vector graphics), DXF, GeoJSON, PGM (for easy antialiasing of pixel-based images), Gimppath, and XFig. Additional backends might be added in the future.

This is their [examples page](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/mkbitmap.html)

Comment: Ok, but how to using this in android programming?

Comment: its the only tool i know that converts from/to the required formats. I haven't tried to integrate it into Android programming but you could contact them. Sorry i couldn't be of more help